# Have Music use files stored in iCloud without Apple Music

Tags: macos, icloud, music.app

How can I have the macOS Music app use my own imported music (without using an Apple Music subscription) while still having the music files backed up to iCloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Close Music.
2. Move your local music files to iCloud. Enter this in Terminal (assumes Document Folders is enabled for iCloud Drive):

   ```
    mkdir --parents ~"/Music/Music/Media.localized/"
    mv ~"/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Music/Music Library.musiclibrary" ~"/Music/Music/Music Library.musiclibrary"
    mv ~"/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Music/Media" ~"/Music/Music/Media.localized/.Media Preferences.plist"
    mv ~"/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Music/Media/Music" ~"/Music/Music/Media.localized/Music"
   ```
3. Link to the iCloud files. Enter this in Terminal:

   ```
    ln -s ~"/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Music/Music Library.musiclibrary" ~"/Music/Music/Music Library.musiclibrary"
    ln -s ~"/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Music/Media" ~"/Music/Music/Media.localized/.Media Preferences.plist"
    ln -s ~"/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Music/Media/Music" ~"/Music/Music/Media.localized/Music"
   ```

Comment: iCloud is not a backup solution, it's a sync solution. Remove a copy from any linked device & it will be removed from all. Be wary.